# How to build an SSISDeploymentManifest via the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, command-line

As part of my auto build I need to have several artifacts for deployment.  One of them is the SSISDeploymentManifest file that is created when I build my SSIS project in Visual Studio 2008 (VS 2010 does not support SSIS/BIDS).

I am trying to find a way to do this from the command line, but the normal stuff is not working (devenv with the /Build and /Project flags...)

Does anyone know how to get this done?

NOTE: I am using TFS 2010 to do the building

OTHER NOTE: I am NOT trying to deploy or run the SSIS package.  I just need the SSISDeploymentManifest file built so that when someone else "blesses" the build it can easily be deployed.  (This means that dtutil and DTEXEC are not what I am looking for.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you ever found a way round this. I've been trying to do exactly the same thing and encountering the same old "Oh but you should be using xyz instead" answers which aren't helpful. In the end I simply built the deployment manifest once using BIDS and then copied it to my solution directory. It never changes (at least for our packages it doesn't) and since the 'build' command doesn't actually do more than copy the dtsx and config file into a folder and write the xml for the deployment manifest, it made sense to simply have my build process copy these files itself, including my pre-built manifest.

That also allowed me to edit out sensitive information (i.e. my domain account name and the domain name itself) from the manifest file. The only thing is if you change your package significantly (re-naming it for example) you'll need to generate a new manifest using BIDS, but it's the best I could come up with and I couldn't justify any more time spent searching for another way.

Comment: I am sorry I did not circle around with my answer.  I ended up using the MSBuildExtensionPack's BuildDeploymentManifest task.  You can find the documentation here: http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/581fb9b8-67dd-ec9d-8c61-77e0d202993c.htm

Comment: Ooh, that's looking promising - thanks for that! I went through the same frustrations as you so I think I might well be taking a close look at this solution. +1 sir!